# How to connect python shell of aws glue to oracle database

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am working on AWS Glue Python Shell. I want to connect the python shell with Oracle database.
I have successfully installed the library but when I tried to connect Oracle using cx_Oracle I am facing the following error

DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have downloaded oracle instant client put it s3 bucket and used its path as library path but still facing the same issue.

```
import cx_Oracle
conn_str = u'{username}/{password}@{host}:{port}/{sid}'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u'select * from hr.countries')
for row in c:
   print(row[0], "-", row[1])
conn.close()
print('hello I am here');
```

Comment: Where the oracle db is located ? And where the glue connection is located? In terms of vpc subnet

Comment: I am trying to connect or on-premise oracle database

Comment: The latest advice is to use [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) (the renamed, major release of cx_Oracle) since it doesn't need the Oracle client libraries (e.g. libclntsh) installed.